# Maria DB Managing JSON

Tags: mariadb, json

I have a field in a MariaDB database with the following information:

```
{"Portal Content":{"Colours":
{"Primary":"String","Secondary":"String","Default":"String"}}}
```

If I wanted to set the primary colour value to green - how would I go about doing this?

I currently have the following code:

```
UPDATE portal_content
SET portal_content_json = JSON_SET(portal_content_json, '$.PortalContent.Colours.Primary', 'Green')
where `portal_attachment_id` = 25
```

When this code runs, I get `0 rows affected`.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

If I remove the `$.` from the path, it blanks the whole column.

Comment: Perhaps you could construct a reproducible example at dbfiddle.uk?

Answer (score 1):

Common misprint. The attribute name in JSON is `"Portal Content"` (contains a space char) whereas you specify the path in the function parameter as `PortalContent`, i.e. without this space char.

```
WITH cte (value) AS (
  SELECT '{"Portal Content":{"Colours":{"Primary":"String","Secondary":"String","Default":"String"}}}'
)
SELECT JSON_SET(value, '$."Portal Content".Colours.Primary', 'Green')
FROM cte
```

| JSON_SET(value, '$."Portal Content".Colours.Primary', 'Green') |
| --- |
| {"Portal Content": {"Colours": {"Primary": "Green", "Secondary": "String", "Default": "String"}}} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EB2Y5Wlu)